# Show a list of woocommerce products on external site with shortcode at the end

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

Some time ago I had a script made up to display my affiliates reference anywhere on my site using this shortcode "**[blog_path_ref]**.

I now have an external woocommerce store that is tracking to my affiliates on our system.  But I need to display a list of all products url's from our external store to our main affiliate site backend, with the affiliate ref at the end (using the shortcode above).

Is there a way to display all our products from one site to another just as url's with the shortcode as the ending to each url?  (Note: I have already added the necessary script to make the shrotcode work on our site)

I have multiple sites but I figure I should at least try to get one working first or if you have a solution that can display from multiple sites, that would be great too.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can create a plugin which will use [WooCommerce REST API](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/)